# Github: Pull request showing trail of merge to master message

Tags: git, github

Whenever I raise a pull request it is showing a trail of merged to master messages and then my commit message. Why this is happening?

Whenever I am done with any feature I create new branch from the master using the below steps.

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout -b new_branch
```

Is anything wrong with this procedure? 
Thanks in advance. [image: ithu]

Comment: look for the commit dates, it should be in descending order, merge commits might have committed later in the dates.

Comment: @ankidaemon Yes those day are of past. But I dont understand everytime I create new branch for new feature from master and raises the PR for new feature it always shows up like this.